# How to find first array items in second object of array items and return matched items from second object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to find first array items in second object of array items and return matched items from second object using JavaScript.

First Array:

`const firstArr = ["foo", "bar"];`

Second Object:

```
const secondObj = {
  "items": [{
    "name": "First item",
    "labels":["foo"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Second item",
    "labels":["foo", "bar"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Third item",
    "labels":["baz"]
  }]
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "name": "First item",
    "labels":["foo"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Second item",
    "labels":["foo", "bar"]
  }]
}
```

I tried something like the following;

```
function updatedVersion() {
  var thirdArr = [];
  for (var array of firstArr) {
    if (secondObj) {
      for (var obj of secondObj.items) {
        for (var label of obj.labels) {
          if (array === label) {
            thirdArr.push(obj);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return thirdArr;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `.data` with ([`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) to produce an array of objects based on membership ([`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) by the `.labels` array ([`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)), then re-build the result object you want afterwards or re-attach the filtered array to `.items`:

```js
const firstArr = ["foo", "bar"];
const secondObj = {
  "items": [{
    "name": "First item",
    "labels":["foo"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Second item",
    "labels":["foo", "bar"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Third item",
    "labels":["baz"]
  }]
};

secondObj.items = secondObj.items.filter(({labels}) => 
  labels.some(e => firstArr.includes(e))
);
console.log(secondObj);
```

Note that we're traversing `firstArr` many times for a complexity of

```
O(data.length * firstArr.length * max(data[_].labels.length))
```

If you make `needles` a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use [`.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) you have

```
O(firstArr.length + data.length * max(data[_].labels.length))
```

assuming constant time lookups on the set. This is premature optimization if your structures are small, and the cost of the `Set` allocation adds overhead.

Similarly, you could make each `labels` array a `Set` and cut costs there if it makes sense to do so for your application.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const firstArr = ["foo", "bar"];

const secondObj = {
  "items": [{
    "name": "First item",
    "labels":["foo"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Second item",
    "labels":["foo", "bar"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Third item",
    "labels":["baz"]
  }]
};

const filtered = {"items": secondObj["items"].filter(item=>item.labels.filter(val =>firstArr.includes(val)).length)}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: `Array#some` seems like a better choice than `filter().length` because it avoids an extra array allocation and is more idiomatic. `some` also gives you early bailout, so once you establish membership, it's pointless to continue iterating as `filter` does.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As `@ggorlen` stated, using `Array#some` is more efficient than using `Array#includes` for each search item.

```js
const firstArr = ['foo', 'bar'];
const secondObj = {
  items: [
    {
      name: 'First item',
      labels: ['foo'],
    },
    {
      name: 'Second item',
      labels: ['foo', 'bar'],
    },
    {
      name: 'Third item',
      labels: ['baz'],
    },
  ],
};

const filter = (o, arr) => ({
  items: o.items.filter((item) =>
    item.labels.some((label) => firstArr.indexOf(label) + 1)
  ),
});

console.log(filter(secondObj, firstArr));
```

Comment: This does a lot of extra work. Once you've found a hit, you can bail early with `Array#some` instead of continuing to call the potentially expensive `Array#includes` on every remaining element. `Array#some` expresses intent best and is more succinct.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but `firstArr.indexOf(label) + 1` could be simply `includes(label)`, at which point we have the same answer. I was suggesting eliminating `reduce`, not `includes`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to be a little creative there.